# Find public key from certificate as a xml string

Tags: windows-phone-7, encryption

i need to find the public key from certificate as xml string. I can take the public key only as a string with this method:

```
public string CelesiPublik()
    {
        X509Certificate cer;
        cer = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("C://certificate//EdonBajrami.crt");

        string Celesi = cer.GetPublicKeyString();
        return Celesi;
    }
```

and then i take this value to the another method. Celesi value now has take celesiPublik

```
  celesiPublik = e.Result;
    string NrTelefonit = "044-419-109";
    string salt = "VotimiElektronikKosove";
    AesManaged aes = new AesManaged();
   Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc2898 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(celesiPublik,Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt));
            aes.Key = rfc2898.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            rsa.FromXmlString(celesiPublik);
            rsa.Encrypt(aes.Key, false);
```

but it shows me error. How can i resolve this problem?

---

GregS i cannot use in Windows Phone 7 X509Certificate2. I take my public key with the method:

```
`X509Certificate cer = new X509Certificate("C://certificate//EdonBajrami.crt");
        string publicKey = cer.GetPublicKeyString();`
```

i can take the public key. Then in another method i take value of the publicKey to another string variable Key:

```
`string Key = publicKey; 
  //-----First------
 RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            //----------
            RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo = new RSAParameters();
            byte[] celesibyte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(celesiPublik);
            byte[] Exponent = { 1, 0, 1 };

            RSAKeyInfo.Modulus = celesibyte;
            RSAKeyInfo.Exponent = Exponent;
            rsa.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);
            //-----------
            /*  rsa.FromXmlString(celesi2Publik); */
            string edon = "Edon";
            byte[] edon1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(edon);
            byte[] edon2 = rsa.Encrypt(edon1, false);'
```

but it sends me data that is 506 byte, i dont understand why, what is a problem ?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell the `X509Certificate` class is nearly useless. Perhaps that is why there is a class `X509Certificate2`? Use the X509Certificate2 class. You can create an `RSACryptoServiceProvider` directly from the public key like the following:

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("C://certificate//EdonBajrami.crt"));  
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider) cert.PublicKey.Key;
```